# Не работает pytest.fail() внутри шага Allure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, allure, pyautogui

Всем привет, появилась проблема - не работает команда прерывания pytest.fail() внутри шага.
При прохождении - происходит игнорирование этого параметра. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо!

```
# coding=utf-8
import pyautogui
import os
import time
import pytest
import allure
from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType
from keyboard import mouse
import keyboard
import io
import cv2


class TestSearchPage:
    @allure.feature('Тестирование платформы 1С')
    @allure.story('Тест №1. Создание выплаты с отметкой на удаление')
    def test_uais(self):
        # Здесь начало шага
        with allure.step('Шаг №1. Открытие тонкого клиента'):
            try:  # Блок ЕСЛИ УСПЕШНО
                program = os.popen('/opt/1C/v8.3/x86_64/1cv8c')
                pytest.fail()
                time.sleep(15)
                fp = io.BytesIO()
                image = pyautogui.screenshot()
                image.save(fp, format='PNG')
                raw = fp.getvalue()
                allure.attach(raw, name='screenshot', attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
            except:  # Блок ЕСЛИ ФЕЙЛ
                fp = io.BytesIO()
                image = pyautogui.screenshot()
                image.save(fp, format='PNG')
                raw = fp.getvalue()
                allure.attach(raw, name='fail-screenshot', attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
                # Конец шага
```

В консоли:

```
[bulkin@1C-fm 1c]$ DISPLAY=:1 pytest test_uais.py
============================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-5.1.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/bulkin/test_cases/1c
plugins: allure-pytest-2.7.1
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                 

test_uais.py .                                                                                                                                                                                             [100%]

================================================================================================ warnings summary ================================================================================================
test_uais.py:8
  /home/bulkin/test_cases/1c/test_uais.py:8: DeprecationWarning: The mouse sub-library is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. Please use the standalone package `mouse`.
    from keyboard import mouse

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
========================================================================================= 1 passed, 1 warnings in 16.20s =========================================================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена - не было в конце кода raise